# Error al validar Email desde un text area - PHP

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de validar los correos que me vienen de un textarea, asumiendo en que en el textarea pueden venir varios campos separados por tabulador, así como es posible que solo venga el correo, el unico campo obligatorio que debe venir en el textarea es el correo.

El problema es que si envio solo el correo sin el nombre no me valida el correo y lo toma como errado.

El correo lo comienza a tomar como errado a partir de la segunda linea y si la envio con solo el correo, el textarea lo tengo preparado para recibir 5 campos separados por tabulador que es como se copia de un excel.

A continuación el código donde valido el correo:

```php
<?php

public function validarEmail()
{   
    //certifico que el textarea llega con todos sus campos a este punto
    $rows = preg_split("/[\n]/", $this->textarea);
    $contador = 0;
    $fallo = 0;
    $array = array();
    $array2 = array();
    $totales = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $email = $name = $lastName = $address = $phone = '';

        list($email, $name , $lastName , $address , $phone) = (explode("\t",$row), 5, null);

        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $contador = $contador + 1;
            array_push($array, $email);
        }
        else {
            $fallo = $fallo + 1;
            array_push($array2, $email);
        }
    }

    $totales = array($contador, $fallo);

    return array($totales, $array, $array2, $rows);
}
```

¿Que debo hacer para que indiferentemente de la lista de correos que envie si solo viene el correo me lo valide correctamente, igual para los campos siguientes?

Un ejemplo para el archivo a seguir sería el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega unas líneas de ejemplo, ¿cómo puede ser el contenido del archivo?, para poder sugerirte algo.

Comment: Listo ya lo edité, el problema hasta ahora lo he identificado cuando solo subo correos a partir de la segunda linea.

Comment: En ese ejemplo se incluyen todos los campos y en la pregunta mencionas que solo el correo es obligatorio, entonces ¿Cómo vendría una fila sin los otros campos, solo con tabuladores adicionales?

Comment: De entrada, es mejor usar explode() que preg_split(), porque realmente no requires el uso de expresiones regulares.

Comment: Al parecer me crea el array con un espacio al final de cada correo, creo que ese es el problema

string(21) "mavibu2011@gmail.com " string(30) "gelateriaeliexpress@gmail.com " string(22) "franyeramos@gmail.com "

Pero no tengo idea donde ocurre eso

Comment: Entonces usa trim() para eliminar los espacios.

Comment: Ya lo intenté pero no funcionó, no los quita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparte de la opción de eliminar espacios, también incluí algunas mejoras al código:

```
<?php

public function validarEmail()
    {   
    //certifico que el textarea llega con todos sus campos a este punto
    // explode() es más eficiente que preg_split() si no necesitas expresión regular
        $rows = explode("\n", $this->textarea);

        $contador = 0;
        $fallo = 0;
        $array = array();
        $array2 = array();
        $totales = array();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $email = $name = $lastName = $address = $phone = '';

            list($email, $name , $lastName , $address , $phone) = array_pad(explode("\t",$row), 5, null);
            // Elimina espacios
            $email = trim($email);
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                $contador ++; // Suma simplificada
                $array[] = $email; // Esto es mejor que array_push() si solo agregas un elemento
            }else{
                $fallo ++;
                $array2[] = $email;
            }
        }
        $totales = array($contador, $fallo);

        return array($totales, $array, $array2, $rows);

    }
```

Comment: Gracias, el trim me funcionó con el explode. Eso era todo